# WPF Slide Content TabItem

Tags: c#, wpf, tabs, styles

I want to acheive a slide effect of the content grid on the tab item when the tab clicked.

this is for example my xaml

```
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >

        <TabControl Name="_menuTabControl" TabStripPlacement="Left" >
            <TabItem Name="MainTab" Header="Main" >


            <Grid>

                <TextBlock     FontFamily="pack://application:,,,/Resources/#Sansation"   FontSize="36"  Text="testing right now" />




            </Grid>
        </TabItem>

        <TabItem Name="_tabItems1" Header="Autologin" >


        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Name="_tabItedms1" Header="Autologin" >


        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>




    </StackPanel>
```

added some style effects

```
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="160"/>

        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border Name="border1"  
                        Background="Transparent"
                        CornerRadius="3,3,3,3"
                       Cursor="Hand"
                        BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"
                        Panel.ZIndex="50"

                        Margin="-7,2,0,0"
                            >

                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"             
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            ContentSource="Header"
                            Margin="10,10,10,10"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>


                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>


                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="100" />
                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="17"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,-2,0" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#cfba6b"/>

                            <Setter TargetName="border1"  
                            Property="BorderBrush" 
                            Value="{StaticResource  glass}" />

                            <Setter TargetName="border1"  
                            Property="Background" 
                            Value="{StaticResource glassef }" />

                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="border1" 
                            Property="Background" 
                            Value="{StaticResource glassef}" />

                            <Setter TargetName="border1"  
                            Property="BorderBrush" 
                            Value="{StaticResource  glass}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

`
i would like to slide the tab item content.
is it can be done only in pure xaml? or i should use c# too?
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the Margin on IsSelected as

```
<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
...
   <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0,0,0" />
```

and if you want the slide effect, you can apply animations using storyboards

```
<EventTrigger  RoutedEvent="Grid.Loaded"> 
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" BeginTime="00:00:00">
                                            <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0,0,0,0" />
                                            <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02" Value="10,0,0,0" />
                                        </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger>
```

Comment: wait where to put it? istead of the setter property?

Comment: You can put it in either Window.Resources or Tabcontrol.Resources or TabItem.Resources

Comment: thank you very much but im getting an exception  `Cannot resolve all property references in the property path Content.Opacity. Verify that applicable objects support the properties.` do you know why it this? @Akansh

Comment: That exception occurs if you do not set the default value for your dependency property. Set a default value for your DP. Use Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"